# ModalPopUpExtender Button EventHandler Not Firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, modalpopupextender, event-handling

I have an eventhandler attached to a button in a modalpopup window. I am trying to pass parameters in the eventhandler but have not had any success. I have tried both lines of code separately and nothing happens when the button is clicked. Is there any other way to pass multiple data from a modalpopup to a method? I've also tried an EventHandler that called a simple method that does not pass any extra parameters and still got nothing.

Thanks

```
save.Click += (object sndr, EventArgs ee) => saveIssueModal(sndr, ee, cguid, ddlStatus.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

or

```
save.Click += delegate(object sender2, EventArgs ee) { saveIssueModal(sender2, ee, cguid, ddlStatus.SelectedValue.ToString()); };
```

...

```
Button save = new Button();
save.Text = "Save";
save.Click += new EventHandler(saveIssueModal);
```

...

```
issuePnl.Controls.Add(save);
```

...

```
IssuesPanel.Controls.Add(issuePnl);
```

...

```
issueMPE = new AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender();
issueMPE.ID = "issueMPE1";
issueMPE.TargetControlID = newBtn.ID;
issueMPE.PopupControlID = issuePnl.ID;
IssuesPanel.Controls.Add(issueMPE);
```

Comment: Are the controls you're creating dynamically surviving the postback, or are they disappearing?

Comment: Which controls the ones in the modalpopup or the main panel? Once the button in the modalpop is clicked the modalpopup disappears.

Comment: Put this code in the OnPreInit event, and try it again. I think your problem has to do with the fact that these controls are generated dynamically.

Comment: Do you mean to create the panel and modalpopupextender in the OnPreInit? I have multiple tabs that have multiple panels in the entire application this is just one of them.

Comment: How about putting the button and modal popup extender in a user control, so that you only have to worry about regenerating one control?

Comment: I've tried to add a user control as a button in the back-end and have gotten nowhere.

Comment: Just thought about something! Does the button do ANYTHING at all when you click it? Do you have any validators on the form or in the dialog?

Comment: The button does nothing, I have the eventhandler method perform basic things like changing the text of a label. I think it may have something to do with the fact that the previous methods called before it are all eventhandlers.

Comment: If nothing happens at all, that would mean something is stopping the button from submitting. Do you have any required field validators on the form? Can you try setting CausesValidation to false on the button.

Comment: Nothing changed when I set CausesValidation to false.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
save.Click += (sender, args) => saveIssueModal(<Custom Arguments>, args);
```

**EDIT:**
Try this for assigning a basic event handler:

```
save.Click += new EventHandler(saveIssueModal);
```

Comment: I tried it but nothing happens. It's as if the eventhandler is not firing. I tried to create an eventhandler without passing extra parameters and still nothing happens.

Comment: See edited comment for assigning an event handler without custom arguments.

Comment: Tried that and nothing happens.

Comment: Okay, then there is a problem somewhere else. Can you post some of your markup, please?

Comment: ...
    Button save = new Button();
    save.Text = "Save";
    save.Click += new EventHandler(saveIssueModal);
...
    issuePnl.Controls.Add(save);    
...
    IssuesPanel.Controls.Add(issuePnl);
...
    issueMPE = new AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender();
    issueMPE.ID = "issueMPE1";
    issueMPE.TargetControlID = newBtn.ID;
    issueMPE.PopupControlID = issuePnl.ID;
    IssuesPanel.Controls.Add(issueMPE);

Comment: Sorry, can you edit your question and include some of this. It's really hard to read.